# What is the equivalent of StreamBuilder but with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I want to automatically update user data, such as username or bio, whenever it changes. I was doing this with a `StreamBuilder`, but I found `Riverpod` and it looks cool. However, I am not sure if it is capable of updating instantly. So, what is the equivalent of `StreamBuilder` with `Riverpod`, if one exists?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/stream_provider/

Comment: I was puzzled how you discovered RiverPod without knowing of StreamProvider?

Comment: I'm doing things backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`StreamProvider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/stream_provider/):

> StreamProvider is similar to FutureProvider but for Streams instead of Futures.

Comment: Free point for you